# Manually copy software (.deb files) from apt-get archives from one machine to another causes fetch error

Tags: 11.10, apt, update-manager

I copied the apt source directory from `/var/cache/apt/archives/` on my laptop (11.10) to my work PC (11.10). I then removed `/var/lib/apt/lists/*`.

Now when I try to update my pc from the terminal, it shows "Failed to fetch" errors. If f use the Ubuntu update manager to install updates, it says: "waiting for unattended-upgrade to exit", but no update happens. Now it won't update anything.

Comment: What is apt source directory? Could you be more specific?

Comment: sorry,copy this directory : `/var/cache/apt/archives/` and then remove: `/var/lib/apt/lists/* ` and now i can't update anything

Comment: Why did you remove apt/lists/? Did you follow some instructions, if so link them please. Also we assume your /etc/apt/sources.list are the same on both machines?

Comment: @Wesley: no, just i think this files not same, so i remove destination list file! i'v done that whitout any guide or manual !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `/var/cache/apt` and delete the `lock` file. Clear the "updates" folder.
Thats it.

Comment: thank you, thats working great. can you explain further about `lock` file; what is it and how it work?

Comment: The 'lock' file can be in /var/lib/dpkg/ directory as well. Use 'sudo rm lock' to remove the lock file in the directory.

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to the '/etc/apt/' directory, with the 'sources.list' file in it? Or the '/var/cache/apt/archives/' directory, where package archives are stored?

Can't really answer your question as to what's wrong without knowing which. If you want to update one machine from the files downloaded by apt-get off another, you're going to need to become familiar with how apt-get structures its package lists and archive files and set up a 'sources.list' file to suit, or use something like apt-mirror.

Comment: sorry,commented